# Replace table column value using part of same column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

I am updating a column in my table, replacing a column with part of its existing value:

```
Update Table_Name Set VarName '12345' where VarName = 'AA-BB-12345';
Update Table_Name Set VarName '99999' where VarName = 'XX-AR-99999';
...
```

How to do this in a loop so it makes changes through entire `Table_Name` table pulling out the last element of `VarName` and using that to update? There are 500 rows to be updated in the table, too many to do single update lines, so I need a loop to accomplish this.

I think this is close:

```
Update Table_Name
set VarName = ( select regexp_substr(VarName, '[^-]+,1,3 ) from Table_Name );
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't that far off, but your subquery isn't correlated - there is no link between the value(s) the subquery finds and the row being updated, so you're probably getting an ORA-01427 error. But you don't need the subquery since you're updating the same row:

```
update table_name set varname = regexp_substr(varname, '[^-]+', 1, 3);
```

You can do it without a regular expression too:

```
update table_name set varname = substr(varname, instr(varname, '-', -1) + 1);
```

which also has the advantage of not nulling any rows which aren't the expected pattern. Even so, you could reduce unnecessary work by only updating values with dashes:

```
update table_name set varname = substr(varname, instr(varname, '-', -1) + 1)
where instr(varname, '-', -1) > 0;
```

or

```
update table_name set varname = regexp_substr(varname, '[^-]+', 1, 3)
where regexp_substr(varname, '[^-]+', 1, 3) is not null;
```

which will only update rows where the old value has (at least) three elements.

The two updates will behave differently if there are two elements - the first one with `substr/instr` will always take the last part after a dash if there are any; The second one with `rexexp_substr` will not update one with a single dash. You've only shown one fixed pattern so none of that may be relevant to you. At least, until you run the same update again against that data...